# Compile error in Controller

Tags: controller, compile-error

> Error: Compile Error: Expecting "]" but was "AND" at line 30 column
>   133

```
accounts = [SELECT id FROM account WHERE id=: acc.id LIMIT 1];
tot=totalRecs = [select count() from Asset WHERE Status = 'Step 1' OR Status = 'Step 2' OR Status = 'Step 3' AND accountid = :accounts.id];
```

This works without a problem if I simply have the following, but I need more than one value from the picklist:

```
accounts = [SELECT id FROM account WHERE id=: acc.id LIMIT 1];
tot=totalRecs = [select count() from Asset WHERE Status = 'Step 1' AND accountid = :accounts.id];
```

Status is a picklist. Am I doing it wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the query itself, you need to use `(` and `)` if you mix `AND` and `OR` operators.

```
1 OR 2 AND 3
```

Is ambiguous in SOQL. You need to use parentheses:

```
(1 OR 2) AND 3
1 OR (2 AND 3)
```

You could simplify your query, assuming you mean (1 OR 2) AND 3 with the IN operator:

```
Status IN ('Step 1','Step 2','Step 3') AND accountid = :accounts.id
```

Comment: Sorry @sfdcfox. The ";" was a typo when creating the question.

Comment: I originally had the ( ) in the wrong place so it didn't work. I removed it, but now I added again in the right location as described by you, sfdcfox. Thank you